# How to change values based on neighboring values on the same column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I am working with a dataset using Pandas dataframe. There are two columns, `timestamp` and `pump_state`. The latter is either 0 or 1.

[image]

Now I want to iterate column `pump_state` and look for the zeros embedded in ones and change them to 1 if the time span between closest 1's is less than 5 minutes.

For example, row 52 to 55. Two 0's are sandwiched by 1's. The timestamp of the 1 before first 0 is 23:52 and that of the 1 after the last 0 is 23.56. The time difference of these two 1's is less than 5 minutes. So the 0's will need to change to 1's. Same thing goes for the 0 at row 65.

I could make a dictionary between timestamp and pump_state and loop through the dict and change the 0's to 1's based on the logic. Then update the dataframe with the new dictionary. But is there a better way (or more Pandas way) to do it?

Comment: Please post your data as text, not a picture, so others can use it for testing. In this case, either you could use `shift(5)` or, if your time data is incomplete, you could `resample` to get all of the time stamps, then use `shift` to do the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following approach (follow comments):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create sample data
NUM = 30
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'timestamp': pd.date_range(start='5/29/2019 00:00:00',
                               periods=NUM, freq='1min'),
    'pump_state': [1] * NUM})
df.loc[5:8, 'pump_state'] = 0  # 4 zeros - 4 minutes < 5 minutes
df.loc[15:25, 'pump_state'] = 0  # 10 zeros - 10 minutes > 5 minutes

# search for rows where 0 switches to 1 and vice versa
df['diff'] = df['pump_state'].diff()
df['diff_1'] = np.where(df['diff'] == 1, 1, -1)
df['diff_-1'] = np.where(df['diff'] == -1, 1, -2)

# merge all found swithces (like join in SQL)
df_support = pd.merge(
    df, df, how='inner',
    left_on='diff_1', right_on='diff_-1')[['timestamp_x', 'timestamp_y']]

# apply timing conditions to all pairs of switches
df_support = df_support[
    # less than 5 minutes
    (df_support['timestamp_x'] - df_support['timestamp_y'] < pd.Timedelta(minutes=5)) &
    # greater than zero
    (df_support['timestamp_x'] - df_support['timestamp_y'] > pd.Timedelta(0))]

# replace 0s with 1s where it is appropriate
for idx, row in df_support.iterrows():
    df.loc[(df['timestamp'] >= row['timestamp_y']) &
           (df['timestamp'] <= row['timestamp_x']),
           'pump_state'] = 1

df.drop(columns=['diff', 'diff_1', 'diff_-1'], inplace=True)
```